# Rolling multiple MSIs into a single EXE

Tags: .net, bootstrapper

I'm using VS2010 and wix3.5 I'm generating 3 different MSI (a driver pack, a tray app and the main app) and I want to install all 3 from a single .EXE file.

I know i need to use a bootstrapper, what is the simplest thing (in terms of ease of use) out there that can just sequentially install my MSIs (they aren't dependent on each other)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend dotNetInstaller.
http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/

Wix 3.6 has Burn, but I don't have any experience with it (yet).
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm

Comment: I ended up using dotNetInstaller as burn wasn't out yet. I haven't tried 3.6 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg/) to create a custom prerequisite package which you can use with the [GenerateBootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164294.aspx) msbuild task.

Comment: The latest release is for vs2008, is it compatible with vs2010?

Comment: I have not tried it, but according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx there is no problem.